# Why cant I implement onclicklistener in my code

Tags: android

Why cant I implement `onclicklistener` in my class. The error I am getting is like this:

```
 The type MainActivity must implement the inherited abstract method 
 View.OnClickListener.onClick(View)
```

Comment: … because you must implement the inherited abstract method `onClick`?

Comment: yes.. i got it.. i needed to do add unimplement method

Comment: @kabuto178 When editing posts, try to fix the titles and improper capitalization as well.

Answer (score 2):

you have to implement the method that is missing see below:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       //code here
    }
```